# Can't pause Interval when click with ReactJS and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jsx, intervals, use-effect, mouseclick-event

I am making slide animation. I want to pause the interval when hover on the Arrow, when click the Arrow, the interval is stilled paused. The interval is only continued when mouse move out the Arrow. But my problem is that when I click the Arrow, the interval continue immediately, not wait until mouse leave out Arrow. I have not been able to fix this.

My project has 3 main components: Slider.js - this is the top Component, SlideContent.js - this one will be run, and Arrow Components

Slider.js:

```
/**@jsx jsx */
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {jsx, css} from "@emotion/core";
import SlideContent from './SlideContent';
import ArrowLeft from './ArrowLeft';
import ArrowRight from './ArrowRight';
// get the width of the viewport
const getWidth = () => {return window.innerWidth}
// css styles for the Slider
const sliderCSS = css`
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    top: 7.5%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
`
const Slider = (props) => {
    // initial state for component Slider
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        activeIndex: 0,
        transition: "left .8s",
    })
    const {activeIndex, transition} = state;
    const {slides} = props;
    // width of the SliderContent, depending on the quantity of the content, each times has 3 visual content so we devide 3
    const slideContentWidth = (slides.length / 3) * getWidth();
    // width of each content
    const slideWidth = slideContentWidth / slides.length;

    MY PROBLEM HERE:
    // animation auto runs SlideContent
    useEffect(() => {
        // auto slide
        const interval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000)
        // next Arrow:
        const nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
        // pause the interval when move mouse into the button, this work
        nextBtn.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        })
        // continue the interval when mouse leave the button
        nextBtn.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            const nextInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000)
            setTimeout(() => {
              clearInterval(nextInterval)  
            }, 2001)
            nextBtn.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                clearInterval(nextInterval)
            })
        })

        // clear interval (Hook syntax)
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    })
    // handler move to the next content
    const nextSlide = () => {
        if (activeIndex >= slides.length - 3){
            try {
                return setState({
                    activeIndex: -0.5,
                    transition: "none"
                })
            }
            finally{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return setState({
                        activeIndex: 0,
                        transition: "left .8s",
                    })
                }, 10)
            }
        }
        setState({
            ...state,
            activeIndex: activeIndex + 1
        })
    }
    // handler move to the previous content
    const previousSlide = () => {
        if (activeIndex === 0){
            try {
                return setState({
                    activeIndex: slides.length - 2,
                    transition: "none"
                })
            }
            finally{
                setTimeout(() => {
                    return setState({
                        activeIndex: slides.length - 3,
                        transition: "left .8s",
                    })
                }, 10)
            }
        }
        setState({
            ...state,
            activeIndex: activeIndex - 1
        })
    }
    return (
        <div css={sliderCSS}>
            <SlideContent 
                slides={slides} 
                contentWidth = {slideContentWidth} 
                slideWidth={slideWidth} 
                left={activeIndex * slideWidth} 
                transition={transition}
            />

            <ArrowLeft handleClick = {previousSlide}/>

            <ArrowRight handleClick = {nextSlide}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Slider;
```

SlideContent.js:

```
/**@jsx jsx */
import {jsx, css} from "@emotion/core";
import Slide from './Slide';

const SlideContent = (props) => {
    const {slides, contentWidth, slideWidth, left, transition} = props;
    return (
        <div css={css`
            width: ${contentWidth}px;
            height: 95%;
            position: absolute;
            left: ${-left}px;
            top: 2.5%;
            display: flex;
            transition: ${transition};
        `}>
           {slides.map((slide, index) => {
               return <Slide key={index} slide={slide} slideWidth={slideWidth}/>
           })} 
        </div>
    );
};

export default SlideContent;
```

ArrowRight.js:

```
/**@jsx jsx */
import {jsx, css} from "@emotion/core";
import rightImage from "../Images/next.png";

const ArrowRight = (props) => {
    return (
        <img 
            src={rightImage} alt="" 
            css={css`
                width: 3%;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 55%;
                right: 12px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 50%;
                &:hover{
                    border: 3px solid yellow;
                };
                box-sizing: border-box;
                &:active{
                    border: 5px solid aqua;
                }
            `}
            onClick={props.handleClick}
            className = "navBtn"
            id="nextBtn"
        />
    );
};

export default ArrowRight;
```

Again, my problem is that the interval is continued immediately when we click the arrow, while I expect to wait until the mouse move out of the arrow.

Update 1

codesandbox as requested is here - https://codesandbox.io/s/slide-auto-dq18t

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a codesanbox where this problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Asutosh, sure you can view my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/slide-auto-dq18t. In my code I have not create event for the left arrow so you can check with the right arrow

Comment: @Asutosh I found the solution, we should not setState inside the interval. That's all.